# Retrieving all neo4j <Record> keys data without using .get()

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am using [neo4j-driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/lib6/record.js%7ERecord.html) in order to run my query:

```
import neo4j from "neo4j-driver";

const driver = neo4j.driver(
  process.env.NEO4J_URI,
  neo4j.auth.basic(process.env.NEO4J_USER, process.env.NEO4J_PASS)
);

export const session = driver.session();
```

When I retrieve the results, I now have to `map` trough all of the records and retrieve all the values in order to format the data that is otherwise in the `_fields` property. Is there a way to do this inside the DB query, or without using separate `.get` calls. I am worried about performance, since the number of nodes will be be big, and mapping trough them could burn unnecessary resources.

```
export const getColorsList = async (): Promise<Color[]> => {
  const readQuery = `
    MATCH (c:Color)-[a:ASSOCIATED_WITH]->(t:Tag)
    WITH COLLECT(t.name) AS tags, c
    RETURN  c.alternativeNames AS alternativeNames, c.hex AS hex, c.name AS name, c.temperature AS temperature, tags AS tags
  `;
  const readResult = await session.readTransaction((tx) => tx.run(readQuery));

  const colors: Color[] = readResult.records.map((color) => {
    const alternativeNames = color.get("alternativeNames");
    const hex = color.get("hex");
    const name = color.get("name");
    const temperature = color.get("temperature");
    const tags = color.get("tags");
    return {
      alternativeNames,
      hex,
      name,
      temperature,
      tags,
    };
  });

  return colors;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a map projection in your query, something like this:

`MATCH (c:Color)-[a:ASSOCIATED_WITH]->(t:Tag) WITH COLLECT(t.name) AS tags, c RETURN  c{.alternativeNames, .hex, .name, .temperature, tags: tags}`

Here's the link to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/maps/).